# Best method to upload big files (successfully) in low bandwidth scenario?

Tags: ftp, bandwidth, crc

My work involves uploading archived files (10-25mb) onto a FTP server (using cuteFTP) on daily basis. Problem is that uploading is done from remote villages where USB datacards give very poor bandwidth. As a result, several files that are uploaded get corrupted.

Two questions:

1. Is there any way to upload the files more effectively? Any mode apart from CuteFTP that takes lesser bandwidth?
2. Also is there any way to check which files have been uploaded correctly by using CRC etc on the fly so that uploader can immediately reupload if there is data corruption while uploading?

I am relatively comfortable with PHP & MySQL.

Any suggestions ... Thanks !

Regards,
DB

Comment: Needs more info about your server

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to split the files before sending? Many ZIP compression utilities support this.

Comment: @ Petteri ... Is there any way to rejoin the parts on the server automatically as the entire file uploads ... and generate a warning to the uploader if there is a problem. I want the uploader to immediately start reuploading corrupted files and not wait for some formal XLSX report next day.

Comment: @ Pekka ... I am not sure about the server details. If you can specify what all info is required I will get back to you ... thnx